# How to format Python variable from table output before insert into a database

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have a variable where the text keyword was extracted from the table form.

Can someone suggest how I can format it properly before inserting it into a database?

[image]

Below is the code and output of the variable:

```
output = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(output)
```

Result from output =

```
1) JP *00000.0000/UNT 0.07704 61628.21 0%(E) 0.00 ND
```

Comment: When you say, "format it properly", what do you mean? Do you want the text to be formatted in a certain way? The string has chars and numbers. Should the text be split based on position or space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first split your string, then convert everything decimal to a float.

```
output='1) JP *00000.0000/UNT 0.07704 61628.21 0%(E) 0.00 ND'
l = output.split()
for idx, le in enumerate(l):
    try:
        l[idx] = float(l[idx])
    except:
        continue
```

`l` is a list

```
['1)', 'JP', '*00000.0000/UNT', 0.07704, 61628.21, '0%(E)', 0.0, 'ND']
```